# JQuery conflict in Sonata-Admin (in Symfony 4 project)

Tags: jquery, sonata-admin, symfony4

I'm having a jquery conflict and I have not solve it following the JQuery's official documentation about noconflict.

I have in the same template the following class that uses jquery:

```
Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType;
```

and on the other hand within the content block of the file,

```
{% block sonata_admin_content %}
```

... I make a call to a jquery file and then I include my script that makes use of jquery:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}"></script>
<script>
....
{# my script #}
....
</script>
```

The problem is that when I include the call to jquery-3.3.1.js the jquery of the DatePickerType stops working: the calendar is not shown.

My standard_layout.html.twig:

```
{#

This file is part of the Sonata package.

(c) Thomas Rabaix <thomas.rabaix@sonata-project.org>

For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
file that was distributed with this source code.

#}

{%- set _preview = block('preview') is defined ? block('preview')|trim : null %}
{% set _form = block('form') is defined ? block('form')|trim : null %}
{% set _show = block('show') is defined ? block('show')|trim : null %}
{% set _list_table = block('list_table') is defined ? block('list_table')|trim : null %}
{% set _list_filters = block('list_filters') is defined ? block('list_filters')|trim : null %}
{% set _tab_menu = block('tab_menu') is defined ? block('tab_menu')|trim : null %}
{% set _content = block('content') is defined ? block('content')|trim : null %}
{% set _title = block('title') is defined ? block('title')|trim : null %}
{% set _breadcrumb = block('breadcrumb') is defined ? block('breadcrumb')|trim : null %}
{% set _actions = block('actions') is defined ? block('actions')|trim : null %}
{% set _navbar_title = block('navbar_title') is defined ? block('navbar_title')|trim : null %}
{% set _list_filters_actions = block('list_filters_actions') is defined ? block('list_filters_actions')|trim : null -%}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {% block html_attributes %}class="no-js"{% endblock %}>
  <head>
    {% block meta_tags %}
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    {% endblock %}

    <meta data-sonata-admin='{{ {
    config: {
    CONFIRM_EXIT: sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('confirm_exit'),
    USE_SELECT2: sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('use_select2'),
    USE_ICHECK: sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('use_icheck'),
    USE_STICKYFORMS: sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('use_stickyforms'),
    },
    translations: {
    CONFIRM_EXIT: 'confirm_exit'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle'),
    },
    }|json_encode()|raw }}'
          >

          {% block stylesheets %}
            {# 'app' must match the first argument to addEntry() in webpack.config.js #}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

            {% for stylesheet in sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('stylesheets', []) %}
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(stylesheet) }}">
            {% endfor %}
          {% endblock %}

          {% block javascripts %}
           {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
           {{ encore_entry_script_tags('subcategorias') }}


            <!-- Renders app.js & a webpack runtime.js file -->
                <script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>
                <script src="/build/app.js"></script> 

            {% block sonata_javascript_config %}
            {% endblock %}

            {% block sonata_javascript_pool %}
              {% for javascript in sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('javascripts', []) %}
                <script src="{{ asset(javascript) }}"></script>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endblock %}

            {# localize moment #}
            {% set localeForMoment = canonicalize_locale_for_moment() %}
            {% if localeForMoment %}
              <script src="{{ asset(
              'bundles/sonatacore/vendor/moment/locale/' ~
              localeForMoment ~
              '.js'
              ) }}"></script>
            {% endif %}

            {# localize select2 #}
            {% if sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('use_select2') %}
              {% set localeForSelect2 = canonicalize_locale_for_select2() %}
              {% if localeForSelect2 %}
                <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2_locale_' ~ localeForSelect2 ~ '.js') }}"></script>
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endblock %}

          <title>
            {% block sonata_head_title %}
              {{ 'Admin'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}

              {% if _title is not empty %}
                {{ _title|striptags|raw }}
              {% else %}
                {% if action is defined %}
                  -
                  {% for menu in breadcrumbs_builder.breadcrumbs(admin, action) %}
                    {% if not loop.first %}
                      {% if loop.index != 2 %}
                        &gt;
                      {% endif %}

                      {%- set translation_domain = menu.extra('translation_domain', 'messages') -%}
                      {%- set label = menu.label -%}
                      {%- if translation_domain is not same as(false) -%}
                      {%- set label = label|trans(menu.extra('translation_params', {}), translation_domain) -%}
                      {%- endif -%}

                      {{ label }}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
          </title>
  </head>
  <body
    {% block body_attributes -%}
      class="sonata-bc skin-black fixed
      {% if app.request.cookies.get('sonata_sidebar_hide') -%}
        sidebar-collapse
        {%- endif -%}"
      {%- endblock -%}
      >

      <div class="wrapper">

        {% block sonata_header %}
          <header class="main-header">
            {% block sonata_header_noscript_warning %}
              <noscript>
                <div class="noscript-warning">
                  {{ 'noscript_warning'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                </div>
              </noscript>
            {% endblock %}
            {% block logo %}
              {% spaceless %}
              <a class="logo" href="{{ path('sonata_admin_dashboard') }}">
                {% if 'single_image' == sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('title_mode') or 'both' == sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('title_mode') %}
                  <img src="{{ asset(sonata_admin.adminPool.titlelogo) }}" alt="{{ sonata_admin.adminPool.title }}">
                {% endif %}
                {% if 'single_text' == sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('title_mode') or 'both' == sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('title_mode') %}
                  <span>{{ sonata_admin.adminPool.title }}</span>
                {% endif %}
              </a>
              {% endspaceless %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block sonata_nav %}
              <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" 
                                                   role="button" title="{{ 'toggle_navigation'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
                  <span class="sr-only">{{ 'toggle_navigation'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</span>
                </a>


                <div class="navbar-left">
                  {% block sonata_breadcrumb %}
                    <div class="hidden-xs">
                      {% if _breadcrumb is not empty or action is defined %}
                        <ol class="nav navbar-top-links breadcrumb">
                          {% if _breadcrumb is empty %}
                            {% if action is defined %}
                              {% for menu in breadcrumbs_builder.breadcrumbs(admin, action) %}
                                {%- set translation_domain = menu.extra('translation_domain', 'messages') -%}
                                {%- set label = menu.label -%}
                                {%- if translation_domain is not same as(false) -%}
                                {%- set label = label|trans(menu.extra('translation_params', {}), translation_domain) -%}
                                {%- endif -%}

                                {% if not loop.last %}
                                  <li>
                                    {% if menu.uri is not empty %}
                                      <a href="{{ menu.uri }}">
                                        {% if menu.extra('safe_label', true) %}
                                          {{- label|raw -}}
                                        {% else %}
                                          {{- label -}}
                                        {% endif %}
                                      </a>
                                    {% else %}
                                      <span>{{ label }}</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                  </li>
                                {% else %}
                                  <li class="active"><span>{{ label }}</span></li>
                                {% endif %}
                              {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                          {% else %}
                            {{ _breadcrumb|raw }}
                          {% endif %}
                        </ol>
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                  {% endblock sonata_breadcrumb %}
                </div>

                {% block sonata_top_nav_menu %}
                  {% if app.user and is_granted(sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('role_admin')) %}
                    <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% block sonata_top_nav_menu_add_block %}
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            {% include get_global_template('add_block') %}
                          </li>
                        {% endblock %}
                        {% block sonata_top_nav_menu_user_block %}
                          <li class="dropdown user-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                              {% include get_global_template('user_block') %}
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        {% endblock %}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
              </nav>
            {% endblock sonata_nav %}
          </header>
        {% endblock sonata_header %}
       {% block sonata_wrapper %}
          {% block sonata_left_side %}
            <aside class="main-sidebar">
              <section class="sidebar">
                {% block sonata_side_nav %}
                  {% block sonata_sidebar_search %}
                    {% if sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('search') %}
                      <form action="{{ path('sonata_admin_search') }}" method="GET" class="sidebar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                          <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ app.request.get('q') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'search_placeholder'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-flat" type="submit">
                              <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endblock sonata_sidebar_search %}

                  {% block side_bar_before_nav %} {% endblock %}
                    {% block side_bar_nav %}
                      {{ knp_menu_render('sonata_admin_sidebar', {template: get_global_template('knp_menu_template')}) }}
                    {% endblock side_bar_nav %}
                    {% block side_bar_after_nav %}
                      <p class="text-center small" style="border-top: 1px solid #444444; padding-top: 10px">
                      {% block side_bar_after_nav_content %}
                      {% endblock %}
                      </p>
                    {% endblock %}
                  {% endblock sonata_side_nav %}
              </section>
            </aside>
                {% endblock sonata_left_side %}

                <div class="content-wrapper">
                  {% block sonata_page_content %}
                    <section class="content-header">

                      {% block sonata_page_content_header %}
                        {% block sonata_page_content_nav %}
                          {% if _navbar_title is not empty
                          or _tab_menu is not empty
                          or _actions is not empty
                          or _list_filters_actions is not empty
                          %}
                          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                              {% block tab_menu_navbar_header %}
                                {% if _navbar_title is not empty %}
                                  <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ _navbar_title|raw }}</a>
                                  </div>
                                {% endif %}
                              {% endblock %}

                              <div class="navbar-collapse">
                                {% if _tab_menu is not empty %}
                                  <div class="navbar-left">
                                    {{ _tab_menu|raw }}
                                  </div>
                                {% endif %}

                                {% if admin is defined and action is defined and action == 'list' and admin.listModes|length > 1 %}
                                  <div class="nav navbar-right btn-group">
                                    {% for mode, settings in admin.listModes %}
                                      <a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list', app.request.query.all|merge({_list_mode: mode})) }}" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-sm{% if admin.getListMode() == mode %} active{% endif %}"><i class="{{ settings.class }}"></i></a>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                  </div>
                                {% endif %}

                                {% block sonata_admin_content_actions_wrappers %}
                                  {% if _actions|replace({ '<li>': '', '</li>': '' })|trim is not empty %}
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                      {% if _actions|split('</a>')|length > 2 %}
                                        <li class="dropdown sonata-actions">
                                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ 'link_actions'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            {{ _actions|raw }}
                                          </ul>
                                        </li>
                                      {% else %}
                                        {{ _actions|raw }}
                                      {% endif %}
                                    </ul>
                                  {% endif %}
                                {% endblock sonata_admin_content_actions_wrappers %}

                                {% if _list_filters_actions is not empty %}
                                  {{ _list_filters_actions|raw }}
                                {% endif %}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </nav>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endblock sonata_page_content_nav %}
                  {% endblock sonata_page_content_header %}
                    </section>

                    <section class="content">
                      {% block sonata_admin_content %}
                        {# La siguiente línea hace referencia al script asset/js/subcategorias.js cargado anteriormente a través de encore  #}
                        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}"></script>


                        {% block notice %}
                          {% include '@SonataCore/FlashMessage/render.html.twig' %}
                        {% endblock notice %}

                        {% if _preview is not empty %}
                          <div class="sonata-ba-preview">{{ _preview|raw }}</div>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if _content is not empty %}
                          <div class="sonata-ba-content">{{ _content|raw }}</div>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if _show is not empty %}
                          <div class="sonata-ba-show">{{ _show|raw }}</div>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if _form is not empty %}
                          <div class="sonata-ba-form">{{ _form|raw }}</div>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if _list_filters is not empty %}
                          <div class="row">
                            {{ _list_filters|raw }}
                          </div>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if _list_table is not empty %}
                          <div class="row">
                            {{ _list_table|raw }}
                          </div>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endblock sonata_admin_content %}
                    </section>
          {% endblock sonata_page_content %}
                </div>
        {% endblock sonata_wrapper %}
      </div>

      {% if sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('use_bootlint') %}
        {% block bootlint %}
          {# Bootlint - https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser #}
          <script type="text/javascript">
            javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement("script");s.onload=function(){bootlint.showLintReportForCurrentDocument([], {hasProblems: false, problemFree: false});};s.src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootlint/latest/bootlint.min.js";document.body.appendChild(s)})();
          </script>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}
 </body>
</html>
```

Finally I discovered the line of code of the conflict, although I can not find an alternative to solve it.

The line of code in question, which is in the file assets/js/aps.js, is as follows:

```
// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

My jquery script works with that line, but the datepicker script does not work. Without it, only the datepicker works.

Comment: Can you write down an error?
I think it stops working because sonata admin already uses jquery.

Comment: Hi Andrius, It does not throw any errors, it just stops working the DatePicker's calendar. I know that Sonata includes jquery, but when I include a new script (my script) that needs jquery, I have to load the jquery-3.3.1.js file to make it work. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you including your script before sonata jquery?

Comment: I've tried everything (or almost), but I can not avoid the conflict between the jquery that uses vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/Resources/views/Form/datepicker.html.twig and the call to jquery <script src = "{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"> </script> that my script uses within the standard_layout.html.twig sonata admin's template.

Comment: Could you copy `standard_layout.html.twig` ?

Comment: I just added the template

Comment: It must be because of second jQuery.
Try to load your script at the the footer. And do not include second jquery

Comment: Hi Andrius, I have tried what you say. Finally I discovered the line of code of the conflict, although I can not find an alternative to solve it. I edit it in the post to see it better.

Answer (score 0):

In datepicker.html.twig template file there are 3 scripts that use jquery with the following structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function ($) { 
  .........
     });
</script>
```

The solution to avoid the conflict is to leave the structure of the scripts in the following way (keeping the global line. $ = Global.jQuery = $; in assets/js/aps.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ......
</script>
```